# a href tag doesn't dowload the pdf i put in the code

Tags: html

when i try to a add hyperlink to download a PDF it doesn't work  it opens the PDF it doesn't download it

a  download href="https://web.stanford.edu/group/csp/cs21/htmlcheatsheet.pdf" dowload >dowload pdf

Comment: please format your code properly that it is readable. You are using the download attribute multiple times if I see right. Use it like this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp. Also, whether the pdf is downloaded or just opened, depends on browser settings.

Answer (score 0):

working with pdf in links is not the trick of html its about your browser settings as [Nadine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7340594/nadine) mentioned,

based on which browser you are using, you need to set your PDF settings to download or open with native pdf reader,
do more search about handling pdf links in browser.
use the following keyword in google search that should provide you lots of links for how to do that:

keyword: set the browser to download the pdf instead of open

also you may do the following instead of clicking the link:

1-Right-click on the link to the document.
2-Select “Save Target As” or “Save Link As.”
3-Save the document to your hard drive. You may want to make a note of where you saved it.
hope that helps.